Does newer CPU includes instruction set for popular hash and crypto algorithms
I mean since the algorithms like SHA256, MD5, AES, RSA are so widely used, so do these kind of popular algorithm get their special instruction set hardwired in newer CPU ?
And if they do, how fast do they get, I mean do they go from 1000s of clock cycles to a single one, or to some 10s or 100s ?
I am obviously assuming that the software I am using on these newer CPUs are compiled using the latest compiler version which utilises these instruction set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set
